# Lambda returns Null From DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS .. created Basic DynamoDB table with "EmailId" as key and added a record to the table "PlayerDetials". Below is my Lambda function. When i test it , it always return Null instead of one record.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    'region': 'us-east-1'
});

var tableName = "PlayerDetails";


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

var params = {

   TableName : tableName,
   Key: { 
         "EmailId" : event.EmailId
        } 
}

docClient.get(params, function(err,data){

 callback(null, data);
})

};
```

Comment: How did you test it? Have you logged what's in your `event`?

Comment: @dashmug i even used a hardcoded string instead of the event.EmailId but the result was the same. I am very confused as its the simplest of function that i can create on AWS lambda

Comment: Again. How did you test it with a hardcoded string? Did you use Lambda console? Did you hook it up to an API Gateway and tested it by sending it a payload?

Comment: Used Test scenario using Lambda console